# Who provides the call-in service for the Stack Overflow podcast?

Tags: support, questions, podcast

I thought at one time the Stack Overflow podcast was using a 3rd party service to allow listeners to call in and leave questions. Now I can't find the name of the service they have used for call in questions.

Can someone please name the 3rd party service providers the Stack Overflow podcast uses to collect questions for their show?

Answer (score 5):

When Fog Creek moved their offices, they got a dial-in phone in house: 646-826-3879.

But they *did* at one time announce a 3rd-party service where you can call in and leave a message which would create an MP3 file. I don't believe they are using that service but it was called [BlogTalkRadio.com](http://blogtalkradio.com).

Answer (score 1):

Joel or Jeff provides this information at the end of each podcast. Dedicated phone number to ask questions for the podcast: 646-826-3879. You can also record an audio file (90 seconds or less) and email it to podcast@stackoverflow.com, please mention your name.